# IIF in Where Part on SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assumption this is my data

```
CREATE TABLE tbUsers (
idUser INT PRIMARY KEY,
nameUser VARCHAR(20),
levelUser BIT
);

INSERT INTO tbUsers VALUES (1,'Cindy',1),(2,'Philip',0),(3,'Veron',0);

CREATE TABLE tbTransactions (
    idTransaction BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    dateTransaction DATE,
    idUserInput INT
);

INSERT INTO tbTransactions VALUES (1,'2019-07-01',1),(2,'2019-07-05',1),(3,'2019-07-05',3);
```

Level user have 2: Admin(1) and Standard(0)

I want if user who view transaction is level Admin(1), than he/she can view all data. But if level Standard(0), he/she only can view his/her data.

If i use IF statement, i can reach my goal. This is IF code:

```
DECLARE @parLevelUser BIT = 1;
DECLARE @parIdUserView INT = 3;

IF(@parLevelUser=1)
    SELECT * FROM tbTransactions WHERE idUserInput IN (SELECT idUser FROM tbUsers)
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM tbTransactions WHERE idUserInput IN (SELECT @paridUserView)
```

How to write in IIF statement? I write this code but show error.

```
DECLARE @parLevelUser BIT = 1;
DECLARE @parIdUserView INT = 3;
SELECT * FROM tbTransactions WHERE idUserInput IN (IIF(@parLevelUser=1,(SELECT idUser FROM tbUsers),(SELECT @paridUserView)));
```

Error message is: **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Comment: A single query will never offer an optimized execution plan the way two separate queries with an `IF` would. In general, you don't want to make it a goal to stuff as many conditions as possible into a single query even where this is possible; the optimizer does not like this at all. Beware of optimizing for query length and "code reuse".

Comment: Incidentally, recent version of SQL Server offer [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security), where tables can be automatically filtered by the engine based on conditions (for example, `SESSION_CONTEXT`). This is not always an appropriate alternative for custom application checks (which are more flexible) but can save on a lot of code when it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with an IIF expression.   Your IF code is the correct way to do this.

By the way, going only by your sample data, there is no need at all to use a filter for "administrators".  If they can simply see all the data, then all you have to do is this:

```
WHERE @parLevelUser=1 OR idUserInput=@paridUserView
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the meaning of your variables, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbTransactions 
WHERE idUserInput = IIF(
  @parLevelUser = 0,
  @paridUserView,
  idUserInput
);
```

If `@parLevelUser = 0` (this means that the user is not Admin, right?) then the `WHERE` clause will be:

```
WHERE idUserInput = @paridUserView
```

and the users will see only their rows.
If `@parLevelUser = 1` (this means that the user is Admin, right?) then the 
`WHERE` clause will be:

```
WHERE idUserInput = idUserInput
```

which returns `true` for all rows so the Admin will see all the rows.
Edit.
You can get the level of the user from `tbUsers` instead of using the variable `@parLevelUser`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbTransactions 
WHERE idUserInput = IIF(
  (select levelUser from tbUsers where idUser = @paridUserView) = 0,
  @paridUserView,
  idUserInput
);
```

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: I want if user who view transaction is level Admin(1), than he/she can view all data. But if level Standard(0), he/she only can view his/her data.

Comment: This is what the code does. If you pass 0 or 1 to @parLevelUser and the id of the user in@paridUserView.